# How to turn off all gpio pin during powering up raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-2, boot, boot-issues, raspi-config

I am trying to control linear acutronix RC servo using raspberry with the help of adafruit servo hat. While powering up raspberry pi without sending any commands linear motor moved to 100 percentage position.so I just wanted to know how I can turn off all gpio pin while powering up raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

At power-up all GPIO are set as inputs.  GPIO 0-8 have pull-ups to 3V3 enabled.  The other GPIO have pull-downs to ground enabled.

During boot some GPIO may be configured differently according to what you have asked for in `/boot/config.txt`.

If this causes problems you need to find an electronic solution as there is nothing you can do about it in software.